# Javascript: Find the second longest substring from the given string Ex: I/p: Aabbbccgggg o/p: bbb

Tags: javascript

Javascript:Find the second longest substring from given string(input and output example added in heading)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Please help on this..I don't have any clue how to solve this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using regular expressions:

```
function yourFunctionName(input){
  let grp = input.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1|$)/ig);
  grp.sort((a,b)=> b.length-a.length);

  if(grp.length <= 0){
    return null;
  }
  else if (grp.length == 1){
    return grp[0];
  }
  else{
    grp.sort(function(a, b){
      return b.length - a.length;
    });

    return grp[1];
  }
}

console.log(yourFunctionName("ööööööðððób"));
```

Or another way which does not use regular expressions...

```
function yourFunctionName(input){
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let counter = [];
  let prevChar;
  let countIndex = 0;

  for (let index = 0, length = input.length; index < length; index++) {
    const element = input[index];

    if(prevChar){
      if(prevChar != element){ 
        countIndex++;
        counter[countIndex] = "";
      }
    }
    else{
      counter[countIndex] = "";
    }

    counter[countIndex] += element; 
    prevChar = element;
  }

  if(counter.length <= 0){
    return null;
  }
  else if (counter.length == 1){
    return counter[0];
  }
  else{
    counter.sort(function(a, b){
      return b.length - a.length;
    });

    return counter[1];
  }
}

console.log(yourFunctionName("aaaaabbbbccdd"));
```

Comment: Thanks..it helps me a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. Get sequences using `RegExp`
2. Sort them based on string length
3. Select second Item

```js
function getSecondSubstring(str){

    let regex = new RegExp(str.toLowerCase().split("").filter((x,i,a)=>a.indexOf(x)===i).join("+|")+"+", "ig")
    let substrgroups = str.match(regex);
    substrgroups.sort((a,b)=> b.length-a.length);
    return substrgroups[1]
}
console.log(getSecondSubstring("ööööööðððób"));
console.log(getSecondSubstring("Aabbbccgggg"));
```

Comment: how about unicode... eg. `ööööööðððób`?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia, made it generic. will work for all type of chars.

Comment: why down vote ?